# definition of damaged passport. is my passport damaged if jacket or cover page is separated from booklet, everything else is intact?

Tags: passports

The jacket or cover page of my passport has separated from the main booklet, everything else is intact including picture, signature, number etc. Will it be considered a damaged passport and can I travel abroad on its basis? Will it be held by immigration officers?

Comment: That sounds like the dictionary definition of damaged.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @David Not my downvote but it's hard to imagine how something that has been broken into two separate pieces isn't "damaged". It's not like it's a small tear on page 17 or something.

Comment: @DavidRicherby To you and me and those more experienced, sure. But some folks are new at this, and sometimes it's hard to imagine how clueless new ones can be.

Comment: @David I'm not sure how much experience is needed to compare a passport with a detached cover against the ordinary English-language use of the word "damaged".

Comment: @DavidRicherby Just as I said. You and I (and others with experience of these bureaucracies) know the answer without thinking. Others are nervous and unsure. The question was politely asked, and wasn't IMO irrational. (Simple, yes, but not irrational or abusive or asking us to do his homework)

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely 'damaged' and will not accepted.

The biometric chip is in the cover, so with the separation you could use a different cover = different biometric chip. If they would accept that, every terrorist would simply use a stolen cover with his real inside pass...

Comment: Or a fake cover, and claiming that the chip stopped working.